# Charging galaxy S4 wirelessly and wired at the same time

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-4, wireless-charging

I got a Qi wireless charger cover for my `Samsung Galaxy S4` along with the charger pad and I was wondering... What happens if I try to charge my phone wirelessly while it's plugged on the cabe **at the same time**?

Is it safe? Does it work? Am I going to set my house on fire?  <del>Perhaps even create a black hole?</del>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Days since Nokia Wireless charging pillow by Fatboy announced People at [Windows Central checked with Nokia](http://www.windowscentral.com/supercharge-nokia-lumia-920-wireless-wired-charging) and officially it doesn't support Dual-charging (And Wireless Charging takes priority, *I know it just doesn't feel right* )

Since then Many Android users have been [asking about](http://androidforums.com/threads/is-dual-charging-possible-wireless-wired.799265/) it in [forums](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513388-usb-charging-wireless-charging-same-time-bad.html),   [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/2rq3bd/can_i_charge_with_wireless_and_wired_at_the_same/) and it seems that Android phones doesn't support Dual-charging either. However there is no official information about which takes higher priority(Wireless or Wired)